# How to move the last multi-cursor in WebStorm?

Tags: ide, webstorm

How to move the last cursor position while using multi-cusor in JetBrains WebStorm using keyboard?

Here is a gif for further understanding.

[image]

Please comment if further information is needed.

Comment: You can set cursor position explicitly with `Alt+click` - just hold `Alt` and click on position you like to set the caret at

Comment: Yeah, right! Thanks. But I'm looking for a keyboard shortcut.

Comment: You can assign a different shortcut to this action in Preferences | Keymap, Editor Actions/Add or Remove Caret

Comment: I don't think that would work because this functionality would need two keyboard shortcuts, - move last multi cursor left and move last multi cursor right. I suppose this is the shortcut you mentioned - https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/multicursor.html. This would need click as a command in the shortcut.

Comment: haven't got what you mean. With `Alt+click` (or  different shortcut assigned to `Add or Remove Caret` action) you can put cursor right on desired position. there are no actions for moving last caret left or right

Comment: I think you partly got it. I'll explain further. I want to be able to position my last multi-cursor with keyboard by moving it left/right. Editor Action `Add or Remove Caret` accepts only a mouse shortcut but not a keyboard shortcut. Please observe the attached gif in the question, the cursor is being moved to left/right without any intervention with mouse. My question is if we can do the exact same with WebStorm using keyboard.

Comment: I did observe that `Clone Caret Above/Below` options in Keymap settings, which are very helpful. However, it'll be even better if there is an option to move the cursor left/right after cloning the cursor.